# Zip file with password, sent with a different extension

Tags: zip, password-protection, unzip

I received a zip file via email that was password protected.  However, my email system was blocking the zip file type, so the sender changed the extension to something else.  I saved the file and renamed it to a .zip.  However, it does not ask for a password to unzip it, and the unzipping fails.

Is there any way that this will work?

Comment: And this has to do with programming how?

Comment: @Pete Good point... but where would I post it?

Comment: @Pete already has an answer, so I can't delete.  Sorry.

Comment: It is related to programming, as if you want to automatically send zip files, for example a new version of a product to your users and the email system blocks the zip extensions, then automatization of the answer described by aaron.bynum might be a good work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that there isn't a double file extension on it (i.e. "file.jpg.zip").

Comment: What is being used to zip/unzip the file? It could just be a matter of the file being corrupted.

Comment: Ah... rookie mistake.  I had to unzip with what they used.  Thanks a bunch.